# Python: get the range between two dotted numbers

Tags: python

I am trying to get the range of numbers between two dotted numbers, like 2.1.0 and 2.1.3.

My requirement is that the first two numbers need to be the same (so not 2.1.0 to 2.2.0)

What I want to get out is:

```
['2.1.0', '2.1.1', '2.1.2', '2.1.3']
```

Here is what I have tried, and it works, but I want to know if there is a better way to do it.

```
start = "2.1.0"
end = "2.1.3"

def get_dotted_range(start,end):
    start_parts = start.split(".")
    end_parts = end.split(".")
    # ensure the versions have the same number of dotted sections
    if len(start_parts) != len(end_parts):
        return False
    # ensure first 2 numbers are the same
    for i in range(0,len(start_parts[:-1])):
        if start_parts[i] != end_parts[i]:
            # part is different betwen start and end!
            return False
    new_parts = []
    # ensure last digit end is higher than start
    if int(end_parts[-1]) >= int(start_parts[-1]):
        # append the version to the return list
        for i in range(int(start_parts[-1]),int(end_parts[-1]) + 1):
            new_parts.append("%s.%s.%s" % (start_parts[0],start_parts[1],i))
    else:
        return False    # end is lower than start

    return new_parts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
start = "2.1.0"
end   = "2.1.3"

def get_dotted_range(start, end):
    # break into number-pieces
    start = start.split(".")
    end   = end  .split(".")
    # remove last number from each
    x = int(start.pop())
    y = int(end  .pop())
    # make sure start and end have the same number of sections
    #   and all but the last number is the same
    if start != end:
        return []
    else:
        head = ".".join(start) + "."
        return [head + str(i) for i in range(x, y + 1)]
```

then

```
In [67]: get_dotted_range(start, end)
Out[67]: ['2.1.0', '2.1.1', '2.1.2', '2.1.3']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
start = "2.1.0"
end = "2.1.3"

startFirst, startMiddle, startLast = map(int, start.split("."))
_, _, endLast = map(int, end.split("."))

dottedRange = [".".join(map(str, [startFirst, startMiddle, x])) 
               for x in range(startLast, 1+endLast)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
start = "2.1.0"
end = "2.1.3"

# split once to get last value
s_spl, e_spl = start.rsplit(".",1), end.rsplit(".",1)
# get first part of string to join up later
pre = s_spl[0]
# make sure first two parts are identical
if pre == e_spl[0]:     
    # loop in range from last element of start 
    # up to and including last element of end
    out = ["{}.{}".format(pre, i) for i in range(int(s_spl[1]), int(e_spl[1]) + 1)]
    print(out)

print(out)
['2.1.0', '2.1.1', '2.1.2', '2.1.3']
```

So in a function we would return a list or False:

```
def get_dotted_range(start,end):
    s_spl, e_spl = start.rsplit(".", 1), end.rsplit(".", 1)
    pre = s_spl[0]
    if pre == e_spl[0]:
        return  ["{}.{}".format(pre, i) for i in range(int(s_spl[1]), int(e_spl[1])+1)]
    return  False
```

You should also consider the cases where a user enters incorrect data that cannot be cast to an int, the format is incorrect or they enter an empty string so you get an error indexing etc...

```
def get_dotted_range(start, end):
    try:
        s_spl, e_spl = start.rsplit(".", 1), end.rsplit(".", 1)
        if s_spl[0] == e_spl[0]:
            pre = s_spl[0]
            return ["{}.{}".format(pre, i) for i in range(int(s_spl[1]), int(e_spl[1]) + 1)]
    except ValueError as e:
        return "{}: Digit expected".format(e)
    except IndexError as e:
        return "{}: Input format should be d.d.d ".format(e)
    return False
```

There are other cases you may want to catch like when a user enters the start and end backwards which will end up returning an empty.

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
def get_dotted_range(start, end):
  sparts = start.split('.')
  eparts = end.split('.')

  prefix = '.'.join(sparts[0:-1])

  slast = int(sparts[-1]) 
  elast = int(eparts[-1]) 

  return [prefix + '.' + str(i) for i in range(slast, elast + 1)] 

print(get_dotted_range('2.1.0', '2.1.3'))
print(get_dotted_range('2.1.9', '2.1.12'))
```

results in:

```
['2.1.0', '2.1.1', '2.1.2', '2.1.3']
['2.1.9', '2.1.10', '2.1.11', '2.1.12']
```